# Problems with Add method in TimeUnit class

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

class TimeUnit
{
public:
    TimeUnit(int m, int s)
    {
        this -> minutes = m;
        this -> seconds = s;
    }

    string ToString()
    {
        ostringstream o;
        o << minutes << " minutes and " << seconds << " seconds." << endl;

        return o.str();
    }

    void Simplify()
    {
        if (seconds >= 60)
        {
            minutes += seconds / 60;
            seconds %= 60;
        }
    }

    TimeUnit Add(TimeUnit t2)
    {
        TimeUnit t3;

        t3.seconds = seconds + t2.seconds;

        if(t3.seconds >= 60)
        {
            t2.minutes += 1;
            t3.seconds -= 60;
        }

        t3.minutes = minutes + t2.minutes;

        return t3;
    }

private:
    int minutes;
    int seconds;

};

int main(){

    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;

    TimeUnit t1(2,30);
    cout << "Time1:" << t1.ToString() << endl;

    TimeUnit t2(3,119);
    cout << "Time2:" << t2.ToString();
    t2.Simplify();
    cout << " simplified: " << t2.ToString() << endl;

    cout << "Added: " << t1.Add(t2).ToString() << endl;
    //cout << " t1 + t2: " << (t1 + t2).ToString() << endl;

    /*cout << "Postfix increment: " << (t2++).ToString() << endl;
    cout << "After Postfix increment: " << t2.ToString() << endl;

     ++t2;
     cout << "Prefix increment: " << t2.ToString() << endl;*/

}
```

I'm having problems with my Add method. Xcode is giving me this error: "No matching constructor for initialization of TimeUnit"

Could someone please tell me what I am doing wrong? I've literally tried everything that I know how to do, but I can't even get it to compile with this method.

Here are the instructions from my professor:

> The TimeUnit class should be able to hold a time consisting of Minutes
>   and Seconds.  It should have the following methods:
>
> A constructor that takes a Minute and Second as parameters ToString()
>   - Should return the string equivilant of the time.  "M minutes S seconds." Test1 Simplify() - This method should take the time and
>   simplify it.  If the seconds is 60 seconds or over, it should reduce
>   the seconds down to below 60 and increase the minutes.  For example, 2
>   Min 121 seconds should become 4 minutes 1 second. Test2 Add(t2) -
>   Should return a new time that is the simplified addition of the two
>   times Test3 operator + should do the same thing as Add Test4 pre and
>   postfix ++: should increase the time by 1 second and simplify Test5

Answer (score 2):

In your `TimeUnit::Add` function, you tried to initialize t3 with default constructor. However, your TimeUnit doesn't have one:

```
TimeUnit Add(TimeUnit t2)
{
   TimeUnit t3;   ///<<<---- here
   ///.....
}
```

Try update `TimeUnit::Add` to this way:

```
TimeUnit Add(const TimeUnit& t2)
{
   return TimeUnit(this->minutes+t2.minutes, this->seconds+t2.seconds);
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thank you! I just need to get it to simplify now.

Answer (score 0):

The specific problem is because there is no `TimeUnit::TimeUnit()` defined, only `TimeUnit(const int &m, const int &s)`.

Comment: I apologize for not posting the instructions earlier, but they are now posted. I'm not allowed to create any more constructors.